# Updating ArrayAdapter issues

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a weird situation with a custom ArrayAdapter.
When I try to update the adpater with new data, instead of the data being updated, the new data are inserted to the beginning of the listview and the old data are remaining and visible once you scroll the listview.

**UPDATE**

It seems that the problem is caused by the ArrayList from the fragment bundle.
If I don't set the listview in the onCreateView from the fragment bundle, my update code works fine, but now I'm puzzled why this:

```
ArrayList<Collection> cityStoresList = fragmentBundle.getParcelableArrayList("stores");     
mStoresList.addAll(cityStoresList);
```

**is causing the items to always remain on the list?**

**END OF UPDATE**

Here are parts of the code: (Collection is a custom object model class)

```
ArrayList<Collection> mStoresList = new ArrayList<Collection>();

/** List Adapter */
private StoresListAdapter mListAdapter;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    boolean attach = false;
    if (container == null) {
        attach = true;
    }

    Bundle fragmentBundle = getArguments();
    ArrayList<Collection> cityStoresList = fragmentBundle.getParcelableArrayList("stores");     
    mStoresList.addAll(cityStoresList);

//inflater code not added here, but is present

mListAdapter = new StoresListAdapter(getActivity(), mStoresList);
        mListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);

return layout;
}
```

My custom adapter is as follows:

```
    public class StoresListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Collection> {

        public StoresListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Collection> array) {
            super(c, 0, array);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // View from recycle
            View row = convertView;

            // Handle inflation
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_store, null);
            }

            // Get the Store
            Collection store = getItem(position);
                    //rest of code follows

            return row;
       }
   }
```

Now when I want to update my adapter I use the following:

```
public void updateAdapter(ArrayList<Collection> storesList, final int listIndex) {
    mStoresList.clear();    
    mStoresList.addAll(storesList);         
        mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
```

And this creates the issue I mentioned. The new items appear fine, but the previous ones are still visible and added after the new ones.
It's like adding the new items in the ArrayList as the first items, instead of just replacing the old ones.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: addAll adds, it doesn't remove anything...

Comment: Yes, but I'm clearing it before adding the new list.

Comment: where do you get storesList from ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found the problem.

Because the whole thing is within a fragment, the oncreateView is actually called when I'm attaching the array, so what happens is that my updateAdapter method is called, the items are added and displayed, before the view is actually visible.

Then the oncreateView method is fired and the original bundle items are being added to the Arraylist....